# get all files from sdcard

Tags: android, sd-card

I want get all  paths files (and their sizes!!) from sdcard.

I change code:

```
List<File> dir = new ArrayList<File>();
List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();

  File root = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());

        scan(root);

        for (File f : dir) {
           scan(f);
        }

public void scan (File path) {

        for (File f : path.listFiles()) {
            if (f.isFile()) {
                files.add(f);
            }
            else {
                dir.add(f);
            }
        }
    }
```

But one problem. I loop "dir" and change him at the same time. And I have exception "java.util.ConcurrentModificationException"

Comment: The edit that you've made to this question has made all of the previous answers irrelevant. Please consider posting a separate question in the future rather than completely changing your existing one.

Answer (score 1):

this `files[i + j] = files[i];` line will causing problem.use this way

```
 for (int i = 0, j = 1; i < files.length; i++) {
        if (files[i].isFile())
            Log.i("file:" + files[i].getName(), " " + files[i].getAbsolutePath());
        else { 
            /* if current file is derictory -> 
            save him in end of array with directoty paths*/
            int testsum=i+j;
            if(testsum<=files.length)
             {
               files[i + j] = files[i];
               Log.i("dir:" + files[i].getName(), " " + files[i].getAbsolutePath());
             }
            else
              {
              }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will prevent the exception but it will still print the first encountered directory repeatedly.

Comment: no i have no idea about it but i think first scan all folder name from sd card then. scan each folder for files.here i just answer your ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException as your question

Comment: see this http://www.cnblogs.com/halzhang/archive/2011/03/08/1977314.html may be helpfull for you..

Comment: if you are not getting any exception then u can acept my answer for others help

Comment: @Alex this is not right way for asking question. why u change your question? you get right answer for this question then accept it and if you have any other question then ask a new one

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this line

```
files[i + j] = files[i];
```

when i = files.length - 1. It is strange line of code.